# Understanding Backbone architecture base concepts

Tags: backbone.js, architecture, overriding

I'm trying to working with backbone but I'm missing it's base concepts because this is the first `JavaScript MVVM Framework` I try.

I've taken a look [to some guide](http://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/understanding-backbone-js-simple-example/) but I think I still missing how it should be used.

I'll show my app to get some direction:

```
// Search.js

var Search = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Templates:{}
};

Search.Models.Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: search.product.defaults || {},
    toUrl:function (url) {
        // an example method
        return url.replace(" ", "-").toLowerCase();
    },
    initialize:function () {
        console.log("initialize Search.Models.Product");
    }
});

Search.Views.Product = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function () {
        console.log("initialize Search.Views.Product");
    },
    render:function (response) {
        console.log("render Search.Views.Product");
        console.log(this.model.toJSON());
        // do default behavior here
}
});

Search.Models.Manufacturer = Backbone.Model.etc...
Search.Views.Manufacturer = Backbone.View.etc...
```

then in my web application view:

```
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/underscore.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/backbone/backbone.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/backbone/Search.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
var search = {};
search.product = {};
search.product.defaults = {
    id:0,
    container:"#search-results",
    type:"product",
    text:"<?php echo __('No result');?>",
    image:"<?php echo $this->webroot;?>files/product/default.png"
};

$(function(){
    var ProductModel = new Search.Models.Product();
    var ProductView = new Search.Views.Product({
        model:ProductModel,
        template:$("#results-product-template"),
        render:function (response) {
            // do specific view behavior here if needed
            console.log('render ProductView override Search.Views.Product');
        }
    });
    function onServerResponse (ajax_data) {
        // let's assume there is some callback set for onServerResponse method
        ProductView.render(ajax_data);
    }
});
</script>
</body>
```

I think I missing how Backbone new instances are intended to be used for, I thought with Backbone `Search.js` I should build the base app like `Search.Views.Product` and extend it in the view due to the situation with `ProductView`.

So in my example, with `render` method, use it with a default behavior in the `Search.js` and with specific behavior in my html view.

After some try, it seems `ProductModel` and `ProductView` are just instances and you have to do all the code in the `Search.js` without creating specific behaviors.

I understand doing it in this way make everything easiest to be kept up to date, but what if I use this app in different views and relative places?

I'm sure I'm missing the way it should be used.

In [this guides](http://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/understanding-backbone-js-simple-example/) there is no code used inside the html view, so should I write all the code in the app without insert specific situations?

If not, how I should write the code for specific situations of the html view?

Is it permitted to override methods of my Backbone application?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should think of the different parts like this:

- templates indicate what should be displayed and where. They are writtent in HTML
- views dictate how the display should react to changes in the environment (user clicks, data changing). They are written in javascript
- models and collections hold the data and make it easier to work with. For example, if a model is displayed in a view, you can tell the view to refresh when the model's data changes
- then, you have javascript code that will create new instances of views with the proper model/collection and display them in the browser

I'm writing a book on Marionette.js, which is a framework to make working with Backbone easier. The first chapters are available in a free sample, and explain the above points in more detail: http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf